# Failed to create an ipc port; access is denied in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm getting an error when I try to open MySQL Workbench:

"failed to create an ipc port : access is denied"

[This is the dialog shown by the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAppe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you give a reboot to your machine, and then try opening up your workbench instance.

According to [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,631720,631805#msg-631805), the above issue is due to a locked resource.

Comment: thanks for reply I have rebooted my system but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to restart system in order to release that port. Just open task manager. Work Bench will be still available there in Task or Process. Just end it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just for others who might face this later. I also faced this issue and figured out that I was logged into the machine console and using mysql workbench there. Once I logged off the machine for that session, it started working again.